# Use vim to search by hex code

Tags: search, vim, hex

I need to clean up a file.  We have an xml parser that runs on it that is failing due to an escape character (0x1B) in the file.  How do I use vim to find where in the file that character is so I can remove it?

Example file:

```
<?php
echo "Hello, world.\n";                           
?>
```

After conversion:

```
0000000: 0a3c 3f70 6870 0a65 6368 6f20 2248 656c  .<?php.echo "Hel
0000010: 6c6f 2c20 776f 726c 642e 5c6e 223b 0a3f  lo, world.\n";.?
0000020: 3e0a
```

So I delete a char: (in this example, the 'H')

```
0000000: 0a3c 3f70 6870 0a65 6368 6f20 22 656c  .<?php.echo "Hel
0000010: 6c6f 2c20 776f 726c 642e 5c6e 223b 0a3f  lo, world.\n";.?
0000020: 3e0a
```

Notice how the first line isn't wide enough anymore.    When I convert it back, I get:

```
^@<?php
echo "el^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Search (e.g. using <kbd>/</kbd>) for `\%x1b`.

You can also type control characters, including escape, into the command line by preceding them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.  So type <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more detail is needed.  Don't bother switching to hex representation.  Vim will show an escape character as `^[`.  Search for it using either of my methods and, with the cursor on it, delete it using `x`.

Comment: For posterity: nerfrubyr's comment was in regards on a comment I deleted when asking for clarification.  It turns out I was typing something wrong.  Both of these ideas work great for this.

Comment: Note for those that have <Ctrl-V> mapped to "paste" (e.g. the default on Windows gvim): You'll need to substitute <Ctrl-Q> for <Ctrl-V> to do the same trick with control characters.

Comment: If you're looking for a range do something like this: /[\x7f-\xff]  You can also look by unicode character /\u001d

Comment: I found that / `\%x1b`, for example, worked great but may I ask: what is the purpose/meaning of the `%`?

Comment: @CraigSilver `\%x` is the prefix needed to search for hex codes. `\x` on its own matches any one hex digit (equivalent to [0-9A-Fa-f]). Searching for `\x1b` will find a hex digit followed by a literal `1b`. See `:help pattern-overview` in Vim.

Comment: Ah, so `\x` is a wildcard for any hex digit, `0-F`, while `\%x` is the prefix for a literal hex number, like `1B`?

Comment: @CraigSilver Yes, exactly

Comment: Does this work for finding UTF-16 characters?

Answer (score 13):

Transform vim into a hex editor by doing  `[escape] :%!xxd`. Then search for 0x1B (`/1B`).

Comment: Once I've opened it in that mode, how do I remove that char and save the file?

Comment: Use h,j,k,l to navigate to the char, press 'r' and enter the new character. Then do escape, :wq to quit&save.

Comment: I am not replacing the character, I am deleting it.  Once it has been delete, the rows don't match up.  Does VIM handle a shorter row when translating from the visual hex back into ascii?

Comment: Ups, sorry-  you need to do switch back to ASCII using ´:%!xxd -r´ before you save. That should do the job, hopefully.

Comment: That yeilds a broken file (presumably due to the mis-aligned lines)  I'm going to edit my answer to show what I mean

Comment: To allow deletion/insertion  I would suggest using the `-p` option both for converting and reverting - this turns off the formatting

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yeah, that may work, but it'll make it harder to find the `1b`: e.g. you may match `31 b7` in the middle and break your file again (and it's not easy when your block is that long — 60 nibbles instead of 4).

Answer (score 6):

You can discover what a hex value of a character by putting the cursor on it and pressing `ga`

Below you will see a hex value of the character. Example for a `<╬>` character

> <╬>  <|N>    206,  Hex ce,  Oct 316, Digr I>

Delete it by :

```
%s/\%xce//g
```

Comment: It's important to note that this will **not** show you the physical bytes as stored in the file but rather the Unicode codepoint. This is not the same. For example for the german letter `Ä` it will show you `Hex 00c4` which relates to `U+00C4` in Unicode. To get the real bytes you can use `g8` which gives you `c3 84` which is the actual UTF-8 encoding of `Ä` used in the file.

Comment: It might be a multibyte character too in which case you want %u or %U. See `:h %u`